# UITextView scrolling without triggering UIPageViewControllerDataSource in UIPageViewController's view controllers

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have multiple view controllers. Something like this:

ViewControllerA
ViewControllerB
ViewControllerC

I use these as my UIPageViewController's view controllers, (as pages).

Each one of them has scrollable UITextViews inside. I cannot disable scrolling because text length should be flexible.

When I scroll the textview, UIPageViewControllerDataSource's viewControllerBefore or viewControllerAfter also is being triggered. How can I prevent this?

Can I disable vertical gestures for UIPageViewController and prevent clashes? Or is there some other way to stop them working at the same time? I want to change page only on horizontal gesture, and scroll the text view only on vertical gesture. But I don't know how to do it. What should I do?

Comment: Please share the code instead of describing it. It’s hard to understand the full picture like that.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Just did a quick test, and I can scroll the text views ***without*** triggering `viewControllerBefore` or `viewControllerAfter`. Some other code is being executed, or you have your page view controller / pages setup incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Thank you @DonMag and @BulatYakupov for trying to help me and warning me about the given information is not enough. I had some restriction on code sharing. Today I found another way. But first here how my screen looks :

[image]

I was swiping to turn the page with page curl.

When I scroll the text, it was also triggering viewControllerBefore or viewControllerAfter. It wasn't changing the page, but It was triggering my view controller creating function. This function keep track of current index on an array to supply data to vc creation.

It is something like this:

```swift
class myCustomVC: UIViewController {
    let textView = UITextView()
}

class PageVCDataService {
    var array = ["John","Josh","Joe","Harvy"]
    //keeping track of the current index for suppling correct text from array for every page
    var currentIndex = 0

    func createAfterPage() -> UIViewController {
        currentIndex += 1
        return createVC(page :array[currentIndex])
    }
    
    func createBeforePage() -> UIViewController {
        currentIndex -= 1
        return createVC(page :array[currentIndex])
    }

    func createVC(page : String) ->UIViewController {
        let vc = myCustomVC()
        vc.textView.text = page
        return vc
    }
}

class PageVC : UIPageViewController {
    let dataService = PageVCDataService()
    // ...some code
}
extension PageVC: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return dataService.createBeforePage()
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return dataService.createAfterPage()
    }
}
```

It wasn't changing the page but it was changing the index. For example if I scroll the text and if my current index at 10 (page 11), my current index was changing to 9. When I swipe for next page, next page was the same page because index was going 9 to 10, which is the same index at the beginning.

So i implemented UITextViewDelegate and used scrollViewDidScroll method. Every time text view scrolls, it send a notification to my data service class, tell it to check if the text on the screen and the text at the current index is same. If it's not, my function find the index for the text on the screen and corrects current index.

It is an ugly solution but maybe it can help someone else.